# Захват экрана Android-устройства в Gstreamer

Tags: android, ubuntu, opencv

Что имеется:

1. Компьютер с Ubuntu + Gstreamer
2. Android-смартфон, подключенный к компьютеру через USB

Я пытаюсь получить вывод содержимого экрана смартфона в Gstreamer для дальнейшей его обработки. Как это возможно сделать?

Пробовал сделать пайплайн из androidscreencast, ничего не получилось.

Comment: Предположительно вы хотите через интерфейс ADB делать последовательно скриншоты и потом закидывать их на видео конвертацию и стримить?

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема - не понятно. Автор больше здесь не появлялся. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39569208/1778421

Comment: Проблема, кажется, очевидна. Есть прямая необходимость получать вывод в Gstreamer(не для вывода, не для просто захвата, а именно для обработки в реальном времени в связке с OpenCV), и простых путей для этого нет. А если автор не появлялся — возможно, это говорит о том, что не было предложено ни одного более или менее адекватного ответа?

Answer (score 5):

1. Установите на Android-устройство бесплатную версию приложения
   DriodCam из Play Market.
2. Установите и настройте [необходимые компоненты на стороне Ubuntu.](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/12/install-droidcam-ubuntu-16-04/)
3. Используйте камеру устройства в Ubuntu как обычное устройство V4L/V4L2

DroidCam не уникален, есть аналоги и для Android и для iOS.

Кстати, подключать шнурок-то не обязательно - через wifi и даже через интернет может работать.

Если же хотите сами сделать то же самое, что DriodCam - тогда тоже всё понятно - есть 2 части, одна на моб. устройстве, другая на клиенте (может выглядеть как драйвер камеры но не обязательно), они между собой снюхиваются, android-программа читает камеру и отправляет клиенту.

Comment: Как правило смартфоны в таких режимах кушают столько энергии, что лучше бы разъем USB использовать для зарядки, что  далеко  не всегда доступно при интерфейсном подключении.

Comment: если нужно постоянная работа камеры - в качестве терминала с камерой можно еще взять RasPi или подобное - дешево, работает и ничего лишнего.